# How to animate a line graph in python where each step of the animation draws an entirely new line based on data in dataframe, and export as gif

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to animate a line graph in python based on data in my df.

- For each step in the animation, a line graph would be displayed using one row of the df.
- A fraction of a second later, a new line graph would be displayed using the next row of data in the df.
- This process would continue until each row of data had been separately displayed.
- After this process had been done for all rows, the graph would show the last line of data.
- I would also have code that converts the animation to a gif and then exports it.

I'm lost as to how to do this and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is the code and df I have so far:

```
# Import dependencies
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Create lists to be converted to df
data = [['01/01/2016', 4.17, 4.42, 4.53, 4.71, 4.77, 4.72], 
        ['02/05/2017', 4.59, 4.64, 4.70, 4.74, 4.80, 4.68], 
        ['04/17/2018', 4.67, 4.82, 4.90, 5.02, 5.20, 5.06], 
        ['03/03/2019', 4.70, 4.79, 4.90, 4.80, 4.50, 3.84], 
        ['08/21/2021', 6.02, 5.47, 5.34, 5.55, 5.44, 5.25], 
        ['09/14/2022', 5.18, 5.25, 5.36, 5.37, 5.27, 4.74],
        ['05/05/2023', 5.32, 5.47, 5.46, 5.52, 5.53, 4.64]
       ]

# Create the pandas df
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'Month 1', 'Month 2', 'Month 3', 
                                 'Month 4', 'Month 5', 'Month 6'])

# Convert 'date' to datetime.
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

# Display df
display(df)

# Create animated line graph as described in my question
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an animation you can read the [guide in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html). Essentially, you will need to create the empty figure and plot a blank line, saving the return of that. Then you will have to create a function that takes the frame number and updates the plot accordingly. I'm assuming your x-axis is the months, so I changed the ticks to have the appropriate text. The `FuncAnimation` returns an object that you can then use to save the animation as a gif.

Note: Rather than letting the `func` use variables from the global scope, I use `functools.partial` to pass the arguments to the function and just leave the frame number left for the animation to iterate through.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [])

xlabels = df.columns[1:].tolist()
x = np.arange(len(xlabels))
ax.set_xticks(ticks=x, labels=xlabels)
ax.set_ylim(df.loc[:,xlabels].min().min(), df.loc[:,xlabels].max().max())

def func_full(i, df, line, x, xlabels):
    line.set_data(x, df.loc[i, xlabels])
    

func = partial(func_full, df=df, line=line, x=x, xlabels=xlabels)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=len(df), interval=500)
ani.save("temp.gif", fps=1, writer="pillow")
```

[image]